# React Native propTypes not working

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, react-proptypes

I'm trying to use `propTypes` for my RN application, but it never seems to be enforced. My component looks something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text } form "react-native";

export class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<Text>...</Text>);
  }
}

Table.propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.string,
};
```

This didn't warn I passed a number into the component from another file like this:

```
<Table data= { 2000 } />
```

So I tried making `propTypes` a static property of `Table` because I saw some stuff about ES6 working with propTypes that way:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text } form "react-native";

export class Table extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.string,
  };

  render() {
    return (<Text>...</Text>);
  }
}
```

Then I tried adding a plugin to my `.babelrc` file

```
"plugins": [
  "transform-class-properties",
]
```

I've tried making the prop required

```
static propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

I've even tried changing the `export class Table...` to `export default class Table...` with no luck. I've tried every combination of the methods listed above to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of this, but you should pass a prop using the "equals" character. <Table data={2000} />. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: That was a typo in my post, my actual code uses `=`, sorry about that, I've fixed it in my post.

Comment: React proptypes work only in development environment, so verify you're not under production env

Comment: Hmm, I assumed that i already was, but I changed something and it started working. not sure if it was the environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to go away by itself when I was fiddling with the code. It may have been an env issue like @asaf david suggested, I'm not really sure. I tried to go back and change stuff back to see if I could reproduce, but I couldn't :(. I'm sorry to anyone searching this in the future.

Comment: i got same problem. how can you fix that? i dont see warning or recommended when press CTRL + Space in VSCode

Comment: Like i said, it somehow fixed itself, and try as I might i wasn't able to reproduce the issue, I'm sorry!